# How to write coercion methods

Tags: r, dispatch, coercion, r-s4, reference-class

I'm having a bunch of custom-made Reference Classes and would like to write coercion methods for some of them. It'd be nice if a function call would look like this:

```
objectCoerce(src=obj, to="list", ...)
```

where `...` is the crucial part as sometimes I want to pass additional stuff for certain coercions (see `do.deep = TRUE/FALSE` below.

However, in order to do that, do I need to implement sort of a "transformer" that takes the `to` argument, tries to instantiate an empty object of the class specified by `to` and then calls the "regular" method dispatch? Or is there a better way?

Below you'll find my current solution. It works, but I'm "loosing" the option to coerce to class `character"` as this class is used to process things to the regular dispatcher and a `to = "character` would result in infinite recursion. Plus, it's a lot of overhead.

### EDIT 2011-12-02

Of course `setAs` would be the first address to check. But the function specified by arg `def` in `setAs` can only take one argument, and often that's too rigid for me. For example, I don't see how I could include the `do.deep = TRUE/FALSE` switch when using `setAs`.

### Class Defs

```
setRefClass(Class="MyVirtual")

setRefClass(
    Class="A",
    contains="MyVirtual",
    fields=list(
        x="character"
    )
)

setRefClass(
    Class="B",
    contains="MyVirtual",
    fields=list(
        x.a="A",
        x.b="numeric",
        x.c="data.frame"
    )
)

setGeneric(
    name="objectCoerce",
    signature=c("src", "to"),
    def=function(src, to, ...){
        standardGeneric("objectCoerce")       
    }
)
```

### Generic Method

```
setGeneric(
    name="objectCoerce",
    signature=c("src", "to"),
    def=function(src, to, ...){
        standardGeneric("objectCoerce")       
    }
)
```

### Intermediate Transformer

```
setMethod(
    f="objectCoerce",
    signature=signature(src="ANY", to="character"),
    definition=function(src, to, do.deep=FALSE, ...){        

    # Transform 'to' to a dummy object of class 'to'
    to.0 <- to
    # For standard R classes
    try.res <- try(eval(substitute(
        to <- CLASS(), 
        list(CLASS=as.name(to.0))
    )), silent=TRUE)
    # For S4 classes
    if(inherits(try.res, "try-error")){
        try.res <- try(eval(substitute(
            to <- new(CLASS), 
            list(CLASS=to.0)
        )), silent=TRUE)
        # For my classes. In order to get an 'hollow' object, some of them 
        # need to be instantiated by 'do.hollow=TRUE'
        if(inherits(try.res, "try-error")){
            try.res <- try(eval(substitute(
                to <- new(CLASS, do.hollow=TRUE), 
                list(CLASS=to.0)
            )), silent=TRUE)
            if(inherits(try.res, "try-error")){
                stop(try.res)
            }
        }
    }
    # Pass transformed 'to' along so the standard method 
    # dispatcher can kick in.
    out <- objectCoerce(src=src, to=to, do.deep=do.deep, ...)
    return(out)
    }
)
```

### Coercion Method 'MyVirtual' to 'list'

```
setMethod(
    f="objectCoerce",
    signature=signature(src="MyVirtual", to="list"),
    definition=function(src, to, do.deep=FALSE, ...){        

    fields <- names(getRefClass(class(src))$fields())
    out <- lapply(fields, function(x.field){
        src$field(x.field)        
    })
    names(out) <- fields

    if(do.deep){
        out <- lapply(out, function(x){
            out <- x
            if(inherits(x, "MyVirtual")){
                out <- objectCoerce(src=x, to=to, do.deep=do.deep, .ARGS=.ARGS)
            }     
            return(out)
        })
    }

    return(out)

    }
)
```

### Test Run

```
x <- new("B", x.a=new("A", x="hello world!"), x.b=1:5, 
    x.c=data.frame(a=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE)))

> objectCoerce(src=x, to="list")
$x.a
Reference class object of class "A"
Field "x":
[1] "hello world!"

$x.b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$x.c
      a
1  TRUE
2  TRUE
3 FALSE

> objectCoerce(src=x, to="list", do.deep=TRUE)
$x.a
$x.a$x
[1] "hello world!"


$x.b
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

$x.c
      a
1  TRUE
2  TRUE
3 FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use setAs to create a coerce method (though one would rather have one's own base class to write the method on, rather than doing this for envRefClass)

```
setAs("envRefClass", "list", function(from) {
    fields <- names(getRefClass(class(from))$fields())
    Map(from$field, fields)
})
```

and then

```
> as(new("B"), "list")
$x.a
Reference class object of class "A"
Field "x":
character(0)

$x.b
numeric(0)

$x.c
data frame with 0 columns and 0 rows
```

? The deep version might be like

```
setAs("envRefClass", "list", function(from) {
    fields <- names(getRefClass(class(from))$fields())
    curr <- Map(from$field, fields)
    recurr <- sapply(curr, is, "envRefClass")
    curr[recurr] <- lapply(curr[recurr], as, "list")
    curr
})
```

I don't have good ideas for combining these, other than to create a psuedo-class 'deep_list' and a coerce method to that. I feel like I'm not understanding your post.

Comment: Martin, thanks for answering. But i'd like to coerce class B to a list, not to class A.

Comment: +1 for the pointer to `Map()`, didn't know that one before. Regarding `envRefClass` you're totally right, but that was just a quick'n'dirty approach. Based everything on the virtual class `MyVirtual` now.

Comment: What I don't like about `setAs`, and that's the reason I started to think about own "reinventing-the-wheel" approaches in the first place, is the fact that `def` in `setAs` will only allow *one* argument. That's too rigid for most of my coercion scenarios (as you said, not easily possible to combine the `do.deep` switch with `setAs`). Hope this clarifies things a bit more.